# Sort javascript Object in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a javascript dynamic menu, and I'm having a few troubles with that, i get a json data and with javascript i want to setup a menu and submenus...

The problem is

```
listMenu[
  {
    id:10,
    name: 'financial',
    submenu: 0,
    icon: 'fa-bar-chart'
  },
  {
    id:11,
    name: 'bill',
    submenu: 10,
    icon: 'fa-bar-chart'
  },
  {
    id:12,
    name: 'Pay',
    submenu: 10,
    icon: 'fa-bar-chart'
  },
  {
    id:13,
    name: 'Contact',
    submenu: 2,
    icon: 'fa-bar-chart'
  }
]
```

What I need to do is relation the `submenu` with the `id` it will be something like this:

- Financial (submenu 0)
- Bill (submenu 10)
- Pay (submenu 10)
- Contact

Comment: Format your question properly, with code using code syntax (four spaces in front of each line). If someone else has to edit your question to do that for you, you have [not lived up to your side of the bargain](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ("proof-read before posting" section). You also mention you want "something like" the example: how much like it? Exactly like it? If not, then this is not a good example and you probably need to write the exact HTML or object structure you'd like to end up with. And finally: **what have you tried**? (if nothing, try first. Otherwise, post code)

Comment: Why does `Contact` have `submenu: 2` if it is a top level menu?

Comment: it having a submenu id dosnt mean its a top menu, what i have to do is check in that array what is top menu and what is not, like bill and pay are submenu from financial then i will append the bill and pay under the financial then i will append the contact under all as another top menu, but if another person have more access to another menus for example in contact i also can have an 'email' submenu with the submenu: 13 (relations with contact), or maybe another top menu on contact making it a submenu.

Comment: So an item can have a submenu value, but not be a top menu?  I'm assuming like Contact above.  In that case, what does the 2 signify?

Comment: in that case there is only 2 top menus and 2 submenus Financial and Contact are the tops and Bill and Pay are the submenu from Financial. but in case if in the future i add another top menu for Contact it will already have a submenu, its just an example i can change it also to 0 to be same as financial at this moment

Comment: So..... what does submenu: 2 mean in that case?  And is the json structure up for modification?  If so you could nest the children in their parents.

Comment: Do [**This DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/kanohu/1/) useful for you?

Comment: what i have is something like this http://jsbin.com/zoboceyigo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @user1748153: Why do you want to sort that array? It seems to be sorted as expected already. Do you want to build a tree structure instead?

Comment: in that way its already in sort by id, but what i need is to sort with the id and the submenu like the submenu 0 means its a top menu and i also have another submenus that will have relations with the id so it will be under the top menu ex Financial > bill = pay

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort an array using some sort of custom logic, use [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

In your case, that would look like this:

```
var listMenu = [
    {id:10, name: 'financial', submenu: 0, icon: 'fa-bar-chart'}, 
    {id:11, name: 'bill', submenu: 10, icon: 'fa-bar-chart'}, 
    {id:12, name: 'Pay', submenu: 10, icon: 'fa-bar-chart'}, 
    {id:13, name: 'Contact', submenu: 2, icon: 'fa-bar-chart'}
]

var sortedList = listMenu.sort( function( a, b ){
    if( a.submenu > b.submenu ){
        return 1
    } else if ( b.submenu > a.submenu ){
        return -1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
})
```

Comment: Since the `.submenu` property is a number, you can simplify the body of the sort callback function to `return a.submenu - b.submenu;`. The series of comparisons there now would only be needed for strings (since you can't subtract them).

Comment: @MichaelGeary While this is true for the smallest codebase, OP seemed inexperienced with programming, so I sought not to confuse them.